# In a fresh Laravel/Livewire install getting a RuntimeException : A facade root has not been set

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-livewire

I'm playing a fresh install of Livewire 2 and Laravel 8, but in trying to run a phpunit test, I'm getting a `RuntimeException : A facade root has not been set.`. I'm tried the standard cache cleaning, but nothing seem to be working. Anyone else seeing this? Below if the full test I'm running.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Http\Livewire\Properties\CreateProperty;
use Livewire\Livewire;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class CreatePropertyTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function form_has_expected_labels()
    {
        Livewire::test(CreateProperty::class)
            ->assertSee('Property Name')
            ->assertSee('Address');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the TestCase's use statement from

`use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`

to

`use Tests\TestCase;`